# Overloading a function to accept a template pointer variable

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, overloading

The push method is used when it is called in the main function. However, even if the argument in the main function is a pointer, it still uses the function `void Push(const DATA_TYPE& newValue)`.

Shouldn't it use the other one since that is the one accepting the pointer? How do I change the arguments in the second function to override the the one if there is a pointer variable?

```
template<typename DATA_TYPE>   
void Push(const DATA_TYPE& newValue)
{
    //do stuff
}

template<typename DATA_TYPE> 
void Push(const DATA_TYPE *newValue)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n everything is nicely explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with the constness.

The issue is that when you call `Push(p)` with a non-const object pointer, `P * p` the first version works exactly when setting DATA_TYPE=`P*`, giving a function signature of `Push( const P* & )`. In comparison, the second version with DATA_TYPE=`P`requires the addition of `const` to the type signature to get `Push( const P* )`. This means the first version is selected instead of the second, since it is an exact match.

Here's an example to clarify what is going on:

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
    template<typename DT>   
    void Push(const DT& newValue)
    {
        std::cout<<"In const DT& version"<<std::endl;
    }

    template<typename DT>
    void Push(const DT *newValue)
    {
        std::cout<<"In const DT* version"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;

    int i=7;

    // Since i is not const we pickup the wrong version
    f.Push( i ); // const DT&  ( DT = int )
    f.Push( &i ); // const DT& ( DT = int* )

    // Here's using a const pointer to show it does the right things
    const int * const_i_ptr = &i;
    f.Push( const_i_ptr ); // const DT* ( DT = int );

    // Now using a const object everything behaves as expected
    const int i_const = 7;
    f.Push( i_const ); // const DT& ( DT = int );
    f.Push( &i_const ); // const DT*  (DT = int );
}
```

Comment: You might have clarified that this means the reference version provides an exact match, but he pointer version still requires a type conversion from `non-const` to `const` pointer, so the reference version is a better match.

Comment: @Keith I agree, hopefully I've addressed that sufficiently now.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this program

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void push(T&)
{
    std::cout << "By ref" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void push(T*)
{
    std::cout << "By ptr" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    push(x);
    push(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs

```
By ref
By ptr
```

Comment: The difference here is the the `template <typename T>
void push(T*)` is a template, where `void Push(const DATA_TYPE *newValue)` is not. I don't see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: Your missing `const`. `&x` is an rvalue and cannot be bound to `non-const` ref.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `const DATA_TYPE& newValue` will match pretty much anything, in your case it matches as reference to pointer `const DATA_TYPE*& newValue`. Try using `std::remove_pointer` [described here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) - from the top of my head i would write:

```
template<typename DATA_TYPE>   
void Push(const typename std::remove_pointer<DATA_TYPE>::type& newValue)
{
    //do stuff
}

template<typename DATA_TYPE> 
void Push(const DATA_TYPE *newValue)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Nothe however that writing templates matching `const T&` along with other template overloads will usually cause `const T&` grab every call, so you should avoid doing things this way.

**EDIT :**

My previous code is not correct, it must be a bit more complex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename DATA_TYPE, bool is_pointer>
struct helper;

template<typename DATA_TYPE>
struct helper<DATA_TYPE, true>{
    static void f(const typename std::remove_pointer<DATA_TYPE>::type*){
        std::cout << "Pointer" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename DATA_TYPE>
struct helper<DATA_TYPE, false>{
    static void f(const DATA_TYPE&){
        std::cout << "Non-pointer" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename DATA_TYPE>
void Push(const DATA_TYPE& newValue)
{
    helper<DATA_TYPE, std::is_pointer<DATA_TYPE>::value >::f(newValue);
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    Push(i);
    Push(&i);
    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected and it doesn't force the caller to use proper const-ness, although I admit it's not as glamorous as my previous solution ;)

Comment: It seems you can't do argument type deduction in that way: http://ideone.com/Ift1s0